# How to retrieve last column from set of data

Tags: java, oop

I'm pretty new to java and I have a question regarding it.

These are my codes and what I had done is that I had filtered out data from a txt file and saved it to another txt file.

What I want to do now is to retrieve a specify column (which is the last column) and use that data for analysis.

I would like to search the last column for the number of times a certain keyword appears.

Whenever there is a match a counter will be incremented and the text is separated with delimiters.

For example, there are a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j in the txt file.
And I would like to retrieve a specify keyword from j itself and have a counter that will increment every time it occurs.

Can anyone advice on how to do this?

These are my codes :

```
import java.io.*;

public class java {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String searchWord = "asiana";

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("D:\\Downloads\\dataAnalysis1.txt"));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("D:\\Downloads\\output.txt"))) {

            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);

                // extract by lines and write to file
                if (line.contains(searchWord)) {
                    out.write(line);
                    out.newLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What doesn't work?

Comment: Can you share the format to text file?  When you say retrieve 'specific' column, is it related to the search term?

Comment: Hi, if its a CSV, then you are having some separator (`,`, or `;`), as you are reading the file, then you have fetched the whole line in `line` variable, you can use [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and then refer to the [.length](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#getLength(java.lang.Object)) on the new array which you will obtain, that should give you last column value

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx, CSV format can't reliably be parsed with a `String.split`, because CSV format allows escaping of delimiter chars with double quotes.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov 
Ok, officially yes, but I am pretty sure, if you will open escaped separator via Excel, then you will be able to see the quotes as well. So depends on the data

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx, just making a note about that particular format feature. I'm not trying to say your method doesn't work - it's just that it depends on data inside the file.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, yes, for sure, good point

Answer (score 0):

as I mentioned

> if its a CSV, then you are having some separator `(, or ;)`, as you are reading the file, then you have fetched the whole line in line variable, you can use String.split and then refer to the .length on the new array which you will obtain, that should give you last column value

**But be aware**, as M. Prokhorov mentioned, if data will contain escaped separator as well, then it will not be working properly, depends on data

```
public static String getLastColumnValue(String value, char separator) {
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630596/how-to-retrieve-last-column-from-set-of-data
        String[] tokens = value.split(String.valueOf(separator));
        //indexed from zero -> length -1
        if(tokens.length>0) {
            return tokens[tokens.length-1];
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

With  test

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.getLastColumnValue("first col;second;foo;fooolastsemicol", ';'));
//fooolastsemicol
System.out.println(StringUtils.getLastColumnValue("first col,second,foo,fooolastcomma", ','));
//fooolastcomma
```

Answer (score 0):

"when you found any match, you can put the result in a string of array/list. and you can return the last element from the list/array";

```
String searchWord = "asiana";
 List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("D:\\Downloads\\dataAnalysis1.txt"));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter("D:\\Downloads\\output.txt"))) {

        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

            // extract by lines and write to file
            if (line.contains(searchWord)) {
                out.write(line);
                list.addLast(line);
                out.newLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //print the last element from the list.
    print: list.get(list.size()-1);
```